# Is it possible to embed the "Focused" view of a TimePicker into another view?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a mobile app in Xamarin.Forms for Android/iOS using the PCL workflow.

I'm looking to have the controls available and functional on page load. Is there a way to take the view that appears when the TimePicker is Focused and have that embedded into the view? Rather than having a field you have to click on first.

I'm assuming if I have access to the TimePicker's Focused View I can use a customer renderer to achieve this, however I do not know how to access that focused view.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've resolved this yet, but there is a .Focus() method for the TimePicker control in Xamarin.Forms. I use it to simulate the tapping on the view, when another view is tapped (by setting a TapGestureRecognizer). For your specific case, you could call the TimePicker.Focus() method in the OnAppearing method of your Page...